# Using a bootstrap popover as a modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fixed, popover

I've used the search and there are so many questions about the bootstrap popover but I have a special question.

Many people asked how to fix a popover, but I want for my popover to have the same function as a bootstrap "modal" (the thingy that appears from the top, let the screen get dark and you have to quit it to get back to the website). My popover has to be clicked, then, it appears and it stays until you click anywhere else, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Why don't you use the modal in the first place? I guess customizing that to what you need could be easier then hacking popovers to behave like modals.

Comment: The problem is, it shouldn't be completely like a modal, it should just appear only when clicked, and disappear when you click anywhere else, no dark screen etc. the modal was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment:

> Why don't you use the modal in the first place? I guess customizing that to what you need could be easier then hacking popovers to behave like modals

In [this issue on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10536) @Fat recommends to use the focus trigger method instead.
However I just realised I once had the same problem on a project and I solved it by hooking in on the available events and performing a little trick:

```
$( '.popover-element' )
    .on( 'show.bs.popover', function ( e ) {
        $( 'body' ).one( 'click', function ( e ) {
            if ( !$( e.target ).parents( '.popover-element' ).length ) {
                // After the popover has been opened we catched a
                // click event that bubbled up to the body element.
                // Since the .popover-element is not a parent of the
                // element (.length === 0) that originated this event
                // we can assume that the user clicked outside of it 
                // and can thus close the popover.
                $( '.popover-element ).popover( 'hide' );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Also see [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and the [popover documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) (especially the methods and events).

---

Here's a version that should be compatible to your source:

```
$( '[rel=popover]' )
    .popover( {
        trigger: 'hover',
        html:    true,
        delay:   500      
    } )
    .on( 'show.bs.popover', function ( e ) {
        var $popover = $( this );
        $( 'body' ).one( 'click', function ( e ) {
            if ( !$( e.target ).parents().filter( $popover ).length ) {
                $popover.popover( 'hide' );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Ok but what is ".popover-element" for?

Comment: .popover-element is the DOM-element that you turn into a popover with Bootstrap.
This should be the same element that you call .popover(); on.
You might want to add some general class to all your popovers and update the snippet with it (replace .popover-element with the correct selector) so you make sure that all your popovers are covered with this fix all at once.

Comment: I am using this:
`$('[rel=popover]').popover(
      {
        trigger: 'hover', // click | hover | focus | manual
        html: true,
        delay: 500,
      });`
and then all my popovers are using this relationship `rel="popover"`
and now I don't know how to implement your version :/

Comment: I updated my answer with code that should be compatible to yours. You only need to replace your code with the one I posted above.

Comment: Ok it disappears now on clicking anywhere, now I want to fix it "until" you click anywhere else :D (I started with javascript last week, I thought it would be easy if I can write normal java) is there any attribute to set the "fade out time"

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "fix it until you click anywhere else", by fixing it do you refer to its position (css position:fixed;)? Or does the popover dissapear even though you click inside it?

Comment: If I move the mouse away form the object, that calls the popover, it disappears after less than a second and I want it to be shown until I close it by clicking on everything but the popover ^^

Comment: For my snippet to work you need to use ```trigger: 'click``` on the popovers or else they will be closed when you stop hovering the calling element. This should do the trick ;)
Already getting a warning for extensive discussion in the comments section, please accept the answer if it solved the original problem and open new questions if any.